# Getting the most recent record of a group

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, group-by

I'm trying to find the most recent record of a group after doing a inner join.

Say I have the following two tables:

```
dateCreated | id
2011-12-27  | 1
2011-12-15  | 2
2011-12-17  | 6
2011-12-26  | 15
2011-12-15  | 18
2011-12-07  | 22
2011-12-09  | 23
2011-12-27  | 24


  code      | id
    EFG     | 1
    ABC     | 2
    BCD     | 6
    BCD     | 15
    ABC     | 18
    BCD     | 22
    EFG     | 23
    EFG     | 24
```

I want to display only the most recent of the groupings:

So the result would be:

```
dateCreated | code
2011-12-27  | EFG
2011-12-15  | ABC
2011-12-26  | BCD
```

I know this can be achieved using the `max` and `group by` functions, but I can't seem to get the desired result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this should get you there:

```
select max(a.dateCreated) as dateCreated
    , b.code
from table1 a
    join table2 b on a.id = b.id
group by b.code
```

Comment: Yep thats all I needed cheers, I'll mark it as correct when it lets me

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your tables are called `a` and `b`, try this:

```
select max(a.dateCreated) as dateCreated, b.code
from a join b on a.id = b.id
group by b.code
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use analytical functions for this. This way, you are still choosing only one result for every code, even if they are two with the same last `dateCreated` (this may or may not be what you actually want as a result)

```
SELECT Code, dateCreated
FROM (  SELECT T2.Code, T1.dateCreated, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY T2.Code ORDER BY T1.dateCreated DESC) Corr
        FROM Table1 T1
        INNER JOIN Table2 T2
        ON T1.id = T2.id) A
WHERE Corr = 1
```